# SQL Query Find sums from one column for two different columns

Tags: sql

I have a Table with Debit Accounts, Credit Accounts and Amount of Transactions between them. I need to take every Account(Which might be debit sometimes and credit sometimes) and add two columns of received amount and sent amount. I tried a few things, but I only can show for example;

Accounts of debit and Sum of Sent money, same with credits.
How can I gather all this parts together?
I want to find distinct of accounts from both columns  Because sometimes one account might be credit, sometimes debit, and also find how much money it sent or recieved
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w78xh.jpg)

```
WITH TRANSACTIONS (ID,Trans_ID_DT,Trans_ID_CR,Amount)
AS
(
  SELECT 2865991,5420422,5434125,279.72 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2865992,5415415,5434125,20.28  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2866486,5415438,5434502,279.72  
)
```

Comment: please provide some sample data and desired output and specify exactly what database you use

Comment: And if possible your code so far

Comment: Please only tag the RDBMS you are using (do not tag multiples). Also, please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your table(s); the `INSERT` statements for some sample data; **YOUR** attempt at a solution; the issues/errors with **YOUR** solution; and the expected output.

Comment: @Sergey              please see updated post

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unpivot the columns to rows and then add the credits and subtract the debits.

In RDBMS that support `UNPIVOT` (like Oracle):

```sql
SELECT account_id,
       SUM(sgn * amount) AS balance
FROM   transactions
UNPIVOT (account_id FOR sgn IN (trans_id_dr AS -1, trans_id_cr AS +1))
GROUP BY account_id;
```

or, using ANSI SQL:

```sql
SELECT account_id,
       SUM(amount) AS balance
FROM   (
  SELECT trans_id_dr AS account_id, -amount AS amount FROM transactions
UNION ALL
  SELECT trans_id_cr AS account_id, +amount AS amount FROM transactions
)
GROUP BY account_id;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE transactions (id, trans_id_dr, trans_id_cr, amount) AS
SELECT 2865991, 5420422, 5434125, 279.72 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2865992, 5415415, 5434125,  20.28 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2866486, 5415438, 5434502, 279.72 FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | ACCOUNT_ID | BALANCE |
> | --- | --- |
> | 5415438 | -279.72 |
> | 5434125 | 300 |
> | 5420422 | -279.72 |
> | 5434502 | 279.72 |
> | 5415415 | -20.28 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fb736e054cc0f99b30d5b2517d4efa22)*

Comment: @NinoGachechiladze Updated for your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T.Trans_ID_DT,SUM(T.Amount)AS SumDebet,0.00 AS SumCredit
FROM TRANSACTIONS AS T
GROUP BY T.Trans_ID_DT
UNION ALL
SELECT Trans_ID_CR,0.00 AS SumDebet,SUM(T.Amount)AS SumCredit
FROM TRANSACTIONS AS T
GROUP BY T.Trans_ID_CR
```

or you need something like this ?